# SELECT .. WHERE ... IN on Android using rawQuery

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, select

I want to query the sqlite database with an array

**Example:**

I have the following case:

```
String[] Group = new String[] {"001", "002", "003"}
```

Check that I use:

```
rawQuery ("Select * from Article Where group = '" + Group + "');
```

It does not work. My question is with which other way I can handle it?

Comment: Is it an "AND" or an "OR" query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: before using this answer, **YOU NEED TO BE SURE THAT THE DATA IN YOUR ARRAY IS SAFE**. If not, you will need to sanitise it to avoid SQL injections.

I am not sure if `rawQuery` supports arrays, I can't find any example.
I would build the query myself via String manipulation. You need to run through your `String[]` and build the list with the following format:

```
expression IN ('value', 'value', ...);
```

with quotes because we are dealing with strings

[See SELECT IN doc here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/in.php)

So I'd go with that:

```
String[] group = new String[] { "001", "002", "003" };

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : group) {
    sb.append("'").append(s).append("',");
}
sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1); // removes the last comma, we don't want it

String query  = "SELECT * FROM Article WHERE group IN (" + sb.toString() + ");";

System.out.print(query);
```

It outputs

```
SELECT * FROM Article WHERE group IN ('001','002','003');
```

Then

```
rawQuery(query);
```